# Treat printer tray as separate printer

Tags: printer, network-printer

A piece of software we use at work doesn't support using separate trays, sizes and colors so I'm wondering if it's possible to set up each tray to as a separate printer accessible on the network?

Comment: If you're using HP networked printers and the HP universal print driver, it's fairly easy to set up multiple printer instances and then set up each to have a preference that points at a certain tray.

Comment: @FiascoLabs: An assurance that it's possible is literally what was asked,  but your comment isn't particularly useful to anybody who wants to accomplish it.  Can you add some clues?  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows you can set up multiple copies of a printer, each with its own settings.

1. Create the printers using "Add a printer" in Devices and Printers.
2. Select the printer and port from the lists shown.
3. When the new printer is installed, go to Printer Properties and click the Advanced tab ⇒ Printing Defaults button and set the printer up the way you want it. Click OK.
4. Now click the General tab ⇒ Printing Preferences button. Check that your settings show there. If not, set them there as well.

That's it. You now have 2 copies of the printer, with different properties.